# Como faço para abrir a largura do body da modal modal-fill-in usando css

Tags: html, css, modal

Não estou conseguindo abrir a largura do body da modal usando css, pois ela está muito estreita e os botões ficam em uma coluna (uns sobre os outros). Algu´me sabe como fazer?

```
<div class="modal fade modal-fill-in" id="modalGenericaFullScreen" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="exampleFillIn"
     role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModalGenericaFullScreen">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="margin: 0 auto;">O que deseja fazer? </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <button id="btn-selecionar-pessoa-como-filial" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon wb-search"></i>Selecionar uma Pessoa Jurídica e utilizá-la como Filial </button>
                                <button id="btn-iniciar-novo-cadastro-filial" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-plus"></i> Iniciar um novo cadastro </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Usado:

```
.modal-dialog {
    /*max-width: 80%; /*largura da modal*/
    /*height: 100%;*/ /*altura da view da modal (não alterar)*/
    /*margin: 0 auto !important;*/ /*centralizar modal horizontalmente*/

    margin-left: 20px !important;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: bootstrap 3 ou 4 ?

Comment: bootstrap 4.... Já tentei de várias maneiras, alterar o body, o dialog, mas não resolve. Estou usando um framework Remark: https://getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/material/base/uikit/modals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma forma de deixar a modal auto-ajustável ao conteúdo, ou seja, ela terá a largura dos botões, que ficarão um ao lado do outro; e se a tela for menor, um botão vai pra baixo do outro.

Em vez de usar `margin: 0 auto` para tentar centralizar o título da modal, use a classe `.text-center`, e utilize a classe `.position-absolute` no ícone **X** de fechar e a classe `.m-auto` no título. Assim vai ficar tudo alinhado, ao contrário de como está.

Acrescente na `div.modal-dialog` as classes `d-inline-block mw-100`, para que a modal tenha a largura ajustável ao seu conteúdo, como falei no início. A classe `.mw-100` é para resetar a propriedade `max-width` fixa que o Bootstrap aplica de acordo com a largura da tela.

Coloque também a classe `.mt-1` nos botões para que eles não fiquem grudados quando ficarem um acima do outro.

> **Obs.:** não esqueça de remover o CSS que você usou (o que está na pergunta).

Vai ficar assim (execute em tela cheia também):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGenericaFullScreen">
  Abrir modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade modal-fill-in text-center" id="modalGenericaFullScreen" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="exampleFillIn" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple d-inline-block mw-100">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModalGenericaFullScreen">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close position-absolute" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title m-auto">O que deseja fazer? </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <button id="btn-selecionar-pessoa-como-filial" class="btn btn-primary mt-1"><i class="icon wb-search"></i>Selecionar uma Pessoa Jurídica e utilizá-la como Filial </button>
                                <button id="btn-iniciar-novo-cadastro-filial" class="btn btn-success mt-1"><i class="icon wb-plus"></i> Iniciar um novo cadastro </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```